# How to recover files from a Macbook that won't boot which has an SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd

My Macbook pro 2011 won't boot completely anymore (can't open it). In the recovery mode, I can see my disk (SSD) but when I want to download the last IOS on my mac, it seems my computer can't find my SSD.

Can anyone help me found out if my computer is retrievable and if not, is there a way I can recover my files from my SSD?

Thank you very much,
Chloe

Comment: I would suggest taking it to a repair shop. Don't try to DIY this task.

Comment: There were 6 different **MacBook Pro** notebooks for 2011, which one exactly do you have and what version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: A1278 (EMC 2554) sorry, not 2011, but mid 2012. I use to have the last version of OS. But not it is asking me to download Mountain Lion

Comment: Are you able to boot it from **macOS Recovery** from the internal **SSD**, or are you using **Internet Recovery** or a **USB** Installer? If you are using **Internet Recovery** or a **USB** Installer to boot it and it **can not** see the **SSD**, then you will not be able to do anything other then replacing the **SSD**.

Comment: I am able to boot if from macOS Recovery from the internal SSD. I can see my disk when on utilities but not when I want to reboot from last IOS version

Comment: Does Target Disk Mode still exist? If yes, it could be an option by booting the Macbook in external drive mode and attach it like an external USB disk to another Mac...

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

**1. The SATA cable connecting your SSD to the Mac is intermittently failing.** This is a common problem in MBPs of that vintage.

The good news is that this means the data itself on the drive is ok, and the internal cable just needs replacing. Alternatively, you could get an external USB enclosure (a box with a USB cable), and put the SSD in there. You may want to get a repair shop to do this.

**2. The drive itself has failed in some way.**

If this is case, then it is very unlikely that your data can be recovered.

Backups of data are essential to prevent data loss from drive failure. This is why macOS has Time Machine.

Comment: Thank you very much ... and yes, I have learned my lesson regarding data backups :)